# I Have Create Dynamic n*n LineEdit in Qt?

Tags: qt, dynamic, qlineedit

[image]

i want create dynamic n*n with QLineEdit object. for example 3*3 or 17*17 QLineEdite.
How Make it?

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a SW service

Comment: Have a look at Qgridlayout